# NodeJS dynamic replicaset array

Tags: node.js

Folks, is there a way to make the following block dynamic, based upon the length of the hosts and ports array?  Either using underscore.each, or something similar?

```
var hosts = ['ip1','ip2','ip3];
var ports = ['port1','port2','port3'];
this.replSet = new ReplSetServers([
    new Server(this.hosts[0], this.ports[0]),
    new Server(this.hosts[1], this.ports[1]),
    new Server(this.hosts[2], this.ports[2])
]);
```

Thanks!

I've tried with no avail:

```
this.servers = [];
_.each(this.hosts, function (this.host) {
    this.servers.push(new Server(this.hosts[0], this.ports[0]));
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax is wrong, the first parameter of the `_.each` callback is the current element and the second one is the index. You can iterate through one of the arrays and use the `index` for selecting the corresponding element in the second array:

```
_.each(hosts, function (element, index) {
    this.servers.push(new Server(element, ports[index]));
});
```

You could also use the `_.map` method:

```
this.servers = _.map(hosts, function (element, index) {
    return new Server(element, ports[index]);
});
```

Comment: is there any harm to define `var servers` and not use `this.servers`? (like in my answer).  Thanks a ton!

Comment: No, there isn't. It depends on the context, what is the `this` object and how you use the variable/property. If it's a temporary value and you don't need it in other parts of the program, using `var` keyword is better.

Answer (score 1):

You have a mistake within the each loop; you are always using hosts[0].

```
var hosts = ['ip1','ip2','ip3];
var ports = ['port1','port2','port3'];

this.servers = [];
_.each(hosts, function (host,index) {
    this.servers.push(new Server(host, ports[index]));
});
this.replSet = new ReplSetServers(this.servers);
```

Besides you can use _.map:

```
var hosts = ['ip1','ip2','ip3];
var ports = ['port1','port2','port3'];
this.servers = _.map(hosts, function (host,index) {
    return new Server(host, ports[index]);
});
this.replSet = new ReplSetServers(this.servers);
```

Answer (score 0):

This works :

```
var servers = [];
_.each(hosts, function (host, index) {
    servers.push(new Server(host , ports[index]));
});
this.replSet = new ReplSetServers(servers);
```

Thanks Guys!